# Python: add axis for an axis specified

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
x=np.zeros((2,3,4,5))
```

For the `x`, is there simpler way to perform `(x[:,1,:,:])[:,np.newaxis, :, :]`?

Comment: `x[:,1:2]` shold do it.  Eve yours you can drop the trailing :, `(x[:,1])[:,np.newaxis]`

Comment: `x[:,1,np.newaxis]` might also work

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do the slicing and expanding dynamically, you an use something like:

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.zeros((2,3,4,5))
element_idx = 1
axis_idx = 1
sliced_array = np.take(x, element_idx, axis=axis_idx)
result = np.expand_dims(sliced_array, axis_idx)
```

If, on the other hand, the axis is fixed (often true) then the solution suggested by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71948522/python-add-axis-for-an-axis-specified#comment127136219_71948522) will work nicely:

```py
result = x[:, 1][:, None]
```